# Fantasy story where a pair of children who travel between two parallel Earths

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I have no idea about the age of this book, only that it can't be all that new. I read it at around the age of ten, which would be 30 years ago.

In the story there was a boy and a girl (if I recall correctly) that were enabled somehow (sadly I can't remember) to shift between two parallel versions of Earth. One was our world and one was a kind of desolate wasteland which was inhabited by frightening monsters.

Locations in the two worlds were mirrored, so that what might be a factory in our world was perhaps a castle in the other world, and this enabled them to get into locations that were inaccessible in one world by getting into the "mirror" location and then shifting.

I only really remember one powerful scene where one child is cornered by a horse like monster with a skull head and is about to be captured, but the child shifts to our world and finds the monster is a horse skull mounted on a post.

Comment: Not the one you're looking for, but this is similar in concept to Piers Anthony's "Split Infinity" trilogy  In that case, it's parallel worlds that are fantasy/futuristic sci fi.

Comment: Title made me think of The Subtle Knife, but that doesn't seem to be it.